# is there a direct connection between view and controller in MVC PHP?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

The thing is, I'm trying to learn about basic MVC in PHP. And, I had read like gazzilions of articles on it.

The thing that is confusing me is that in half of them they say that there is no direct connection between controller and view and in other half they say that controller has direct connection with view. I don't know which one is correct I was just confused, and I thought its better to clear my concept in the beginning, So someone please guide me.

And also if you can give a link of articles regarding this, that'll be nice of you.

Comment: Depends on the implementation of MVC as it is different per framework. Pick a framework and learn it. Laravel, Codeigniter, something.

Comment: MVC should be framework agnostic

Comment: @MikelBitson..so your saying that there is no hard and fast rule for it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller handles the model and view layers to work together . The Controller is also only connected to a single View and to a single Model, making it a one way data flow system, with handshakes and signoffs at each point of data exchange. 
http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php